# How to send a message through the exchanger if not yet consumer (RabbitMQ)?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I am able to receive the message only when the receiver is running before of the sender.
But I need to be able to send a message while the receiver is not running.
And get it when the receiver starts.
Is it possible?

c# example:

```
//Send
 Channel.ExchangeDeclare(ExchangeName,"direct");
 Channel.BasicPublish(ExchangeName, "MyRoute", null, body);

//Receive (other app)
 Channel.ExchangeDeclare(ExchangeName,"direct");
 String queueName = Channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
 Channel.QueueBind(queueName, ExchangeName, "MyRoute");
 QueueingBasicConsumer consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(Channel);
 Channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);

 BasicDeliverEventArgs Message=consumer.Queue.DequeueNoWait(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating an auto-delete queue:

```
String queueName = Channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
```

so when you close the consumer, the queue is deleted automatically.

if you want do that, you have to create an durable queue, than bind the queue to the Exchange, like this:

```
channel.queueDeclare("yourQueue", true, false, false, null);
```

In this way you don't need the consumer up and running. If the consumer is down the messages will be stored to the queue.

Comment: I send to Exchange.
And especially do not create queues.
As in this example http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-dotnet.html

Comment: here `Channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName` you create a queue. Check the console or execute `rabbitmqctl list_queues` and you will see the queue.

Comment: the exchange does not store the messages.

Comment: You are right.
But I create it in the receiver. As a temporary queue.
Why do I need Exchange?

Comment: I don't know, it depends from your application . Maybe you can solve just using a queue.

Comment: See http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html

The exchanges are there to route messages to queues. A message could be routed to more than one queue